# $xy>0 \iff x$ and $y$ have the same sign proof verification

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, real-numbers

Given the axiom about real numbers that:

1. $a>b$ and $c>0 \implies ac>bc$

and the following facts about real numbers:

2. $0\cdot a = 0$
3. $-(-a)=a$
4. $a(-b)=(-a)b=-(ab)$
5. $a>0\iff -a<0$
6. $a>b$ and $c<0\implies ac<bc$

I want to show that $xy>0\iff (x<0$ and $y<0$) or ($x>0$ and $y>0$). I'm hoping folks can check my approach.

For the $xy>0 \implies$ '$x$ and $y$ have the same sign' direction, I proceeded by proving the contrapositive: $$\text{if } (x\ge0 \text{ or } y\geq0)\text{ and }(x\leq0\text{ or }y\leq0), \text{ then } xy\leq0$$
The part of the solution I'm concerned with is the following:

> This reduces to proving that if one or both of $x$ and $y$ are zero, then $xy=0$ or if w.l.o.g. $y<0<x$, then $xy<0$.

Clearly by fact $(2)$ we have $xy=0 $ if one or both of $x$ and $y$ are zero. If $y<0<x$ (we could have chosen $x<0<y)$, then letting $a=x$, $b=0$, and $c=y$ in fact $(6)$, we have $xy<0\cdot0=0$ so $xy<0$. So in any case, we have $xy\leq0$.

For the other direction, if $(x<0$ and $y<0$) or ($x>0$ and $y>0$) then $xy>0$, first assume $x<0$ and $y<0$. Then $-x>0$ and $-y>0$ by $(5)$. Then $(-x)(-y)=(-(-x))y=xy>0\cdot0=0$; where the first equality follows from $(4)$, the second equality from $(3)$, and the inequality from letting $a=-x$, $b=0$, and $c=-y$ in $(1)$. Lastly, if both $x$ and $y$ are positive, then by $(1)$ again letting $a=x$, $b=0$, and $c=y$ we have $xy>0 \cdot0=0$. Thus we have in either case, $xy>0$.

Hence $xy>0 \iff x$ and $y$ have the same sign.

Comment: In general terms : It looks mostly right , though a bit too long ....

Comment: It is your Post , you have the right to make it look however you want , including mixing up MathJAX & normal text in the textual flow. I just wanted to know , **what was wrong with my edits ?** I can avoid what-ever I did wrong , next time !